# Is this PHP redirect insecure?

Tags: php, header

Hmm I can't really indentify any insecurities but was wondering whether you can, if so how to possibly patch/mend?

Heres the code:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/search/{$_POST['term']}/{$_POST['type']}");
```

The site which i'm redirecting too does the validation & sanitization on their side, but what I'm concerned about is - is this redirecting insecure in any way (on my side - seeing as I'm using direct `$_POST`'s).

Appreciate all help.

PS: Just became curious as I've always thought using unsanizited user input is dangerous (or atleast that applies to XSS and SQLi).

Comment: Viewed in isolation there are no security issues I can see with this.  Assuming you own domain A, and are redirecting user to domain B which you do not control, this in itself should yield no problems.

Comment: Better safe than sorry: `urlencode()` isn't much to type.

Comment: Yes, since the POST values will come from the front-end (manipulated by the end user), which means the end user can append commands to it. So, in my opinion this should be sanitized before it gets to this statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Overall, for most websites running a modern version of PHP, **it is secure**.

There are two concerns at hand:

- A malicious user may be able to trick a victim into unwittingly visiting any page of the form `/search/*/*` on the site by linking them to a malicious page that POSTs to the page with your redirect. (Note that they are not limited to just two slashes after`/search` because their POST variables may contain slashes.) This is similar to handing someone a shortened bit.ly URL that redirects them, so it's not too bad.
- [HTTP response splitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_splitting). If a malicious user includes newlines (specifically, CRLF / `\r\n`) within their POST data, they can cause your `header()` call to output multiple headers, including headers to set cookies, and so on. However, as of PHP 5.1.2 [this has been fixed](http://php.net/releases/5_1_2.php).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a security issue, but you should probably URL-encode these arguments with `urlencode($_POST['term'])`.

Comment: This is a good fix. I might use [`rawurlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) which is expressly "for protecting literal characters from being interpreted as special URL delimiters."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's quite insecure. One should NEVER EVER put unchecked user input into a script. I'd recommend, at a **minimum**, using [filter_input_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) to sanitize your $_POST array before doing anything with it.

Comment: Can you clarify? What security issues could arise?

Comment: It's an XSS brute-force vulnerability on the destination URL. I know it seems like there's no issue here, but I've watched whitehat programmers get root access to my clients' servers through constructed URLs that allowed unchecked user input in their construction.

Comment: @Brian could you ellaborate? and filter_input_array has a variety of filters - so i'm slightly confused on which is appropriate (due to my understanding of what the exact vulnerability is).

Comment: @Brian but the attack is a vulnerability on the 3rd party site, it is not caused by an exploit in the code above.

Comment: @Hamish so I guess the OP has no responsibility to try to protect the third party site from an attack? Remind me never to let you redirect to my site.

Comment: @Brian Well, no - and it doesn't protect the 3rd party from an attack, it merely hopes to mitigate a single vector (out of the millions available). This is moot, however, the question was whether there was a vulnerability for the OP, not the 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the web tier that receives the redirected URL from the client will perform validation on the URL as a whole, so you're probably safe. But it wouldn't hurt to run the two fields through simple validation before sending the redirect.